# vat number required on Magento-2 checkout

Tags: magento2

How can I make the vat number required in the Magento-2 checkout?

I enabled the field as required from admin panel and now i want to make it required during checkout shipping step.
I have followed the steps described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220922/magento-2-checkout-how-to-make-vat-number-required) but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be enabled via admin panel:

```
Stores > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options > Show Tax/VAT Number
```

The **possible** options are:

- No
- Optional
- Required

[image]

On **checkout**

[image]

Now, other possibilities are :

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNdch.png)
If you navigate to:

> Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > (Change
>   Scope to correct website/store view) > Create New Account Options >
>   Show VAT Number on Storefront
>
> Change dropdown to Yes.

You'll then have to set up your tax classes/tax rules/customer groups and then in the above section you can assign the correct values to the groups.

[image]

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/vat-validation-configure.html

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDupa.png) From **Database**

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_required` = '1' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 36;
```

[image: it's working]